# Does the zeta regularized Laplacian determinant measure the volume of some parameter space? How many "spanning trees" on a manifold?

Tags: co.combinatorics, riemannian-geometry, sp.spectral-theory, spectral-graph-theory, spanning-tree

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, with Laplacian $\Delta$. If $\lambda_i$ are the nonzero eigenvalues of $\Delta$, we can define the zeta function $\zeta(s) = \Sigma \lambda_i^{-s}$. By analytic continuation using the Mellin transform and the heat kernel, we can define $e^{ - \zeta'(0)}$, which is the 'zeta regularized determinant.'  (See, for example, [this paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.486.558&rep=rep1&type=pdf).)

For a finite graph $G$, if $L$ is the combinatorial laplacian, we can make similar definitions. Then $e^{- \zeta_L'(0)} / |G|$ counts the number of spanning trees. (Essentially a reformulation of Kirkoffs tree-matrix theorem.)

Question: Is there a parameter / moduli space of geometric objects associated to $(M,g)$ whose volume $e^{- \zeta'(0)} / Vol(M)$ computes?

For example, if $M = S^1$, then $\zeta_{S^1}(s) = 2 \zeta(2s)$, for the usual Riemann zeta function, and $exp( - \zeta_{S^1}'(0) ) = 2 \pi$... which has a clear interpretation, though it's not clear that the clear interpretation is correct.

I asked a similar question in the comments of my previous question here: [What is $e^{- \zeta_{\Delta} '(0)}$ for a $\Delta$ the Laplacian of a manifold?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304274/what-is-e-zeta-delta-0-for-a-delta-the-laplacian-of-a-manifold/304286?noredirect=1#comment758955_304286)

Comment: This may not be relevant, but is Gauss' circle problem related?  My reasoning is due to an injective mapping (or folding) of M w.r.t. the Riemann sphere.  This may allow the derivation of glb and lub  (or some such variation) to determine computability of your target volume.  ....   .....  possibly.....