# Discrete approximation of Minkshisundaram-Pleijel zeta function?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, computational-geometry, spectral-graph-theory, zeta-functions

I'm looking for some references on the following situation:

$S$ is a Riemannian surface, and $G_n$ is a sequence of metric subgraphs embedded on $S$. Let $\zeta_n$ be the zeta function of the Laplacian of $G_n$ (Mellin transform of $Tr (h_t) - 1$, where $h_t$ is the heat kernel of $G_n$), and let $\zeta_S$ be the Minakshisundaram–Pleijel zeta function of $S$.

Under what conditions and for what modes of convergence do we have $\zeta_n(s)  \to \zeta(s)$, $\zeta_n'(s) \to \zeta'(s)$, etc.

I'm particularly interested in the convergence of $exp( - \zeta_n'(0) ) / |G_n| \to exp( - \zeta'(0)) / Vol(S)$.

(This relates to my question here: [Does the zeta regularized Laplacian determinant measure the volume of some parameter space? How many "spanning trees" on a manifold?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304445/does-the-zeta-regularized-laplacian-determinant-measure-the-volume-of-some-param) )

Answer (score 4):

This is an old idea that has been investigated thoroughly by Patodi and  Dodziuk. 
See [their paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5d09/6cc45cb316b7960439844e7bad7186a1e0a2.pdf) for more details. But what they proved is more subtle (about Hodge Laplacian vs metric Laplacian). Later Muller used their techniques to prove his part of the Cheeger-Muller theorem.

For the volume ratio analogy I think I answered [in the previous post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/304274/what-is-e-zeta-delta-0-for-a-delta-the-laplacian-of-a-manifold/304286#304286). The paper I mentioned there specifically showed that minus some exceptions, we should have (2.6.1)
$$
\frac{\log(T_{an}M_{i})}{\textrm{volume}(M_{i})}\rightarrow -\frac{1}{6\pi}
$$
if their conjecture holds based on another result of Muller. But I think some (non-artihemetic) [counter-examples](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1510.06292.pdf) have been found already.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand your objection to the volume ratio now: since the determinant of the Laplacian of the circle is the Riemann zeta function regardless of scale, this ratio goes to zero as the circle grows. This is unlike a cycle graph, where the number of spanning trees (determinant / volume ratio) grows as the cycle grows.

Comment: Although, for a metric cycle graph, where the edge length scales down, then the volume ratio also goes to zero (like $n (1/n)^{n-1}$).

Answer (score 1):

I learned of a few results that give useful answers to (the spirit of) this question:

Zeta functions, heat kernels and spectral asymptotics on
degenerating families of discrete tori ( G. Chinta, J. Jorgenson, and A. Karlsson ) : https://arxiv.org/pdf/0806.2014.pdf

The asymptotic determinant of the discrete Laplacian (Richard Kenyon):
https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0011042

Generally these results look like the following:

We consider a natural sequence of graph $G_n$ converging to a surface $U$. The asymptotics of the log number of spanning trees of $G_n$ is given (roughly) by $[\text{some geometric properties of U}] n^2  + \text{laplacian determinant of U} + constants + o(1)$.

(For the rectangular grid graph case, see especially proposition 13 in Kenyon's paper and compare to formula 105 here: https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104271130 ]

The papers I linked treat the case where $U$ is a torus or a rectilinear polygon in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $G_n$ is either a sequence of discrete tori, or subgraph $\epsilon \mathbb{Z}^2 \cap U$.

I'd be really interested in seeing to what extent these can be generalized...